# How to hide this inline CSS in dev tools

Tags: jquery, css, inline

I have used external css only, due to jquery plugin inject it shows inline in dev tools(chrome). 
And I am not able to track them. Is there any method to hide them? 
 Link: https://nikki158.github.io/Namrata_Portfolio/

[image]

Comment: It added by your jquery plugin `imagesLoaded`

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "hide" them? What purpose does that serve? What does it matter?

Comment: What's your question?

Answer (score 0):

Write new style(your style) class in your `css` file,and add that **class to the element** using the jquery function.

Answer (score 0):

Like [jagjeet-singh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9768562/jagjeet-singh) mentioned it is inserted dynamicly by the plugin which loads the images. To get the division large enough it sets the resulting height of the inserted pictures to the wrapper.

Of course you could set a css selector to add the value by an external css file and then comment auf the line in that plugin to get rid of the inline style.

But to be honest i see no valid point for such a thing :D